# Mouse moves too fast and triggers other button functions - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a div with 12 buttons, laid out in a grid. Each button has a JS mouseenter() that fades out the other 11 buttons. Works great when you move the mouse slowly. But if you move the mouse too fast over another button, the mouseleave() function does not run, and the wrong buttons get faded in or out. Doing research, trying to figure out the best way to deal with this.

Is it a matter of when to add/remove eventListeners? Or setting up some kind of delay, so that the buttonFade() functions only run when the mouse is parked for a few milliseconds?

My page right now with the funky behavior is www.finleyfilms.com.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `setTimeout` and wait for, for example, 500ms and trigger your keyframe or other css then. Otherwise, if the mouse is moved before 500ms, you remove the timeout.

```
const timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
  button.addClass("realTrigger");
}, 500);
button.mouseleave(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  button.removeClass("realTrigger");
});
```